# Parse JSON object as List

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have problem when I try to parse JSON result using httpwebrequest not webclient (because webcleint Not working with the webservice cookies), please help me to parse it because its complex result.

The JSON result is:

```
{"d":"[{\"RefSymbol\":1,\"SymbolFactor\":100000,\"PriceCase\":1,\"RefPriceCase\":1,\"ID\":57,\"Type\":1,\"Name\":\"EUR\/CHF\",\"Bid\":1.2194,\"Ask\":1.2214,\"High\":1.2215,\"Low\":1.2185,\"LastQuoteTime\":\"24\/04\/2014 18:18:30\",\"SpreadOffset\":0,\"PriceOffset\":0,\"SpreadType\":\"1\",\"StopTradeIfNoPrices\":true,\"StopTradeAfterSeconds\":40,\"MaxAmountPerDeal\":10,\"MinAmountPerDeal\":1,\"AskWithSpread\":1.2214,\"BidWithSpread\":1.2194,\"Commission\":50,\"LimitOffset\":0,\"StopOffset\":0,\"PipLocation\":-4,\"Spread\":20,\"IsUsed\":true,\"IsDisplay\":false,\"HasPriv\":true,\"JustClose\":false,\"BuyOnly\":false},{\"RefSymbol\":1,\"SymbolFactor\":1000,\"PriceCase\":1,\"RefPriceCase\":1,\"ID\":58,\"Type\":1,\"Name\":\"EUR\/JPY\",\"Bid\":141.41,\"Ask\":141.46,\"High\":141.79,\"Low\":141.04,\"LastQuoteTime\":\"24\/04\/2014 18:18:35\",\"SpreadOffset\":0,\"PriceOffset\":0,\"SpreadType\":\"1\",\"StopTradeIfNoPrices\":true,\"StopTradeAfterSeconds\":40,\"MaxAmountPerDeal\":100,\"MinAmountPerDeal\":10,\"AskWithSpread\":141.46,\"BidWithSpread\":141.41,\"Commission\":50,\"LimitOffset\":0,\"StopOffset\":0,\"PipLocation\":-2,\"Spread\":5,\"IsUsed\":true,\"IsDisplay\":false,\"HasPriv\":true,\"JustClose\":false,\"BuyOnly\":false},
....
```

---

```
private void FireRequest2()
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mywebservice/")) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar);
        int numVisibleCookies = response.Cookies.Count;
        RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

    }, request);
}
```

Comment: Please include a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Not a JSON dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use Json2cSharp.com to create your class

```
public class Result
{
    public int RefSymbol { get; set; }
    public int SymbolFactor { get; set; }
    public int PriceCase { get; set; }
    public int RefPriceCase { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public string LastQuoteTime { get; set; }
    public int SpreadOffset { get; set; }
    public int PriceOffset { get; set; }
    public string SpreadType { get; set; }
    public bool StopTradeIfNoPrices { get; set; }
    public int StopTradeAfterSeconds { get; set; }
    public int MaxAmountPerDeal { get; set; }
    public double MinAmountPerDeal { get; set; }
    public double AskWithSpread { get; set; }
    public double BidWithSpread { get; set; }
    public int Commission { get; set; }
    public int LimitOffset { get; set; }
    public int StopOffset { get; set; }
    public int PipLocation { get; set; }
    public object Spread { get; set; }
    public bool IsUsed { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisplay { get; set; }
    public bool HasPriv { get; set; }
    public bool JustClose { get; set; }
    public bool BuyOnly { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Then use JSON.NET to deserialize the result

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mywebservice/")) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
{
    HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) req2.EndGetResponse(ar))
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }

    }

}, request);
```

Comment: I have tried but with no luck, i have edit my question with the request i use (Please check), it give me error , would you please advice

Comment: Thank you very much Shawn Kendrot i have made small edit on your answer and its working properly you can check.

Comment: Hey, your edit got rejected as it did not improve the answer. It would be easier to stick with my answer and then do root.result.FirstOrDefault() to get the first item. Of course name your objects whatever you like.